# Generate json file using curl xml

Tags: json, linux, xml, curl, redhat

I'm trying to generate json file using curl and also assign specific path where in the json file will store once generated, but I tried some commands but no json output.

May I know what I need to add or change with my command?

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" --user "admin:Test1234" https://test.com/adventure/
```

Comment: Did you first test the endpoint with Postman or another tool to make sure that it can answer with JSON responses ?

Comment: Hi @totok, Apologize but this is new to me, may I know how will I test that part? by the way I also tried to add **-o myfile.json** before the url https but I got endless upload I guess or what, is it normal?

Comment: correction with endless upload, that was endless spent and no response with Dload when I execute the command

Answer (score 0):

I test a simple curl for a json public api and send de response to a file and the result is a JSON output.

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" https://catfact.ninja/fact >> cat.json
```

You can try it using https://reqbin.com/req/javascript/c-vdhoummp/curl-get-json-example

Or simply using postman and see the code snippet option to check cUrl code snippet.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOuMa.jpg

Comment: I tried this also but the json file not generate the data its an empty file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to generate JSON file. I `add -k` on my command since my URL is HTTPS.